# Как убрать скроллбар из TableView QML?

Tags: qt, c++, qml

Добрый день!

Собственно, вопрос из темы: Как убрать скроллбар из `TableView`? Я новичок и документация с гуглом мне не помогли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`verticalScrollBarPolicy` отвечает за политику отображения http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-scrollview.html#verticalScrollBarPolicy-prop

```
TableView {
    verticalScrollBarPolicy: Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff
}
```